# Accessing nested array in javascript?

Tags: javascript

lets say I have an array that looks like this:

```
var arr = [{
    "id": 1,
    "content": "[{\"number\":1,\"name\":\"Image\",\"description\":\"\",\"fields\":\"[{\\\"number\\\":1,\\\"text\\\":\\\"Image Test\\\",\\\"description\\\":\\\"\\\",\\\"responseType\\\":\\\"Image\\\",\\\"options\\\":\\\"[]\\\"},{\\\"number\\\":2,\\\"text\\\":\\\"test2\\\",\\\"description\\\":\\\"\\\",\\\"responseType\\\":\\\"Text\\\",\\\"options\\\":\\\"[]\\\"}]\"}]"

}];
```

I'm trying to access the content which is a nested array.

Im doing this:

```
var myArray = JSON.parse(arr.content);

console.log(myArray);
```

But this always returns this error:

```
SyntaxError: JSON Parse error: Unexpected identifier "undefined"
```

what I'm I doing wrong here?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```js
myArray = JSON.parse(arr[0].content);
```